# I do not know how to make fade = 0 without attaching it to pin 0 on the arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

My problem is that fade cannot be 0 without connecting it to pin 0 but fade is when the rgb led fades. so I do not know what to do. here is my code:

```
int red=9;
int green=10;
int blue=11;




void setup() {
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  for (int fade=0; fade <=100; fade=fade+5);

analogWrite (red, fade);
delay(30);
digitalWrite(red, 0); analogWrite (green, fade);
delay(30);
digitalWrite(green, 0); analogWrite (blue, fade);
delay(30);
digitalWrite(blue, 0);

}
```

Comment: What observable behavior do you want from your LEDs?

Comment: This likely doesn't compile. Am I correct? You have a `;` after your `for` loop. The compiler likely optimizes that out. If you want to loop everything after your `for` you need to enclose it in curly braces and remove that semicolon.

Comment: Im trying to get it to fade from red to green to blue repeat

Answer (score 1):

A for loop will run whatever is the next statement after it until the case in the middle fails.

If you put a semicolon after your for loop like this:

for(int i=0; i<10; i++);

then that "next statement" is just an empty semicolon.  So it does nothing 10 times.  Or more likely that gets optimized away.

If you want to run several statements together in the for loop, then you need to surround those statements with a set of curly braces to group them together into a compound statement or "block".  You do this for for loops as well as while and if statements.

```
void loop() {
  for (int fade=0; fade <=100; fade=fade+5) //<- NO SEMICOLON
  {  //<- OPENING BRACE
    analogWrite (red, fade);
    delay(30);
    digitalWrite(red, 0); analogWrite (green, fade);
    delay(30);
    digitalWrite(green, 0); analogWrite (blue, fade);
    delay(30);
    digitalWrite(blue, 0);
  }  // <- CLOSING BRACE

}
```

Comment: if I add a semicolon the fade below will not be in the scope

Comment: Right.  Why would you add a semicolon?